# Merge table cells using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to merge table cells for a particular column using jQuery.

Input table:
[image]

Result table:
[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: please show your mark up and what jquery you are currently using, how are the tables built? is the data static? why do you need to do it programmatically? please remove the white space on the images

Comment: @atmd _"why do you need to do it programmatically?"_ - I assume OP wishes to merge subsequent cells of the same value in a given column. This would be an interesting question - nothing ground-breaking, of course.

Comment: The table i given is for a example .My actual need is i have a jquery data table my requirement is ,consider 10 th column in that table, compare each row's 10th column text with next row's 10th column if it matched means we need to merge that first row's 10th cell and second row's 10th cell  .this my requirement.

Comment: Add a code snippet ...

Comment: @JánosWeisz you're prob correct, I wrote the comment in the hope of getting the question updated with more context and code samples added. Alas.

Answer (score 3):

## [LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yahuxajuwi/1/edit?html,js,output)

You can give class to third row and then using below jQuery you can merge cells.

## HTML & jQuery

```js
$('.third-row td:eq(2)').attr('rowspan','2').parent().next().find('td:eq(2)').remove()
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
 <td>1</td>
 <td>1</td>
 <td>1</td>
 <td>1</td>
</tr><tr class="third-row">
 <td>1</td>
 <td >2</td>
 <td>3</td>
 <td>4</td>
</tr><tr>
 <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
 
 <td>5</td>
 <td>6</td>
</tr></table>
```

## Update :

Without adding class to row you can achieve this by jQuery's `eq()` function.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is what you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      
      var el = $("tr td:last-child");
      for(var i = 0; i < el.length; i++){
        if (el[i].innerHTML == el[i+1].innerHTML){
          el[i].setAttribute("rowspan","2");
          el[i+1].parentElement.removeChild(el[i+1])
        }
      }  
      
      
    });
```

```css
td, th, tr, table {
      border: solid 1px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <table corder="1" class="reference" style="width:100%">
    <tbody><tr>
     <th>Number</th>
     <th>First Name</th>
     <th>Last Name</th>  
     <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>Eve</td>
     <td>Jackson</td>  
     <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>John</td>
     <td>Doe</td>  
     <td>80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>3</td>
     <td>Adam</td>
     <td>Johnson</td>  
     <td>80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>Jill</td>
     <td>Smith</td>  
     <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

Comment: Note that inside the for loop is just javascript code, no jQuery.